# how to get root exception of BindException in @ExceptionHandler

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-mvc, bean-validation

I want to handle all controller exception in `@ControllerAdvice` class, but when catch `BindException`, I can't find the root exception.

here is my codes:

**Controller:**

```
@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<UserDto> add(@Valid UserDto user) {
    return ResponseEntity.ok(user);
}
```

**UserDto:**

```
public class UserDto {

    private String name;
    private Gender gender;

    /*setter and getter*/
}
```

**Gender:**

```
public enum Gender {

    FEMALE, MALE
}
```

**Converter:**

```
@Component
public class GenderConverter implements Converter<String, Gender> {

    @Override
    public Gender convert(String source) {
        try {
            return Gender.valueOf(source.toUpperCase());
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown gender value \"" +   source +
                    "\", gender value should be [female, male]");
        }
    }
}
```

**When I post gender=m**, there's the exception message:

```
org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
Field error in object 'userDto' on field 'gender': rejected value [m]; codes [typeMismatch.userDto.gender,typeMismatch.gender,typeMismatch.org.tings.learning.spring.mvc.model.Gender,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [userDto.gender,gender]; arguments []; default message [gender]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'org.tings.learning.spring.mvc.model.Gender' for property 'gender'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@javax.validation.constraints.NotNull org.tings.learning.spring.mvc.model.Gender] for value 'm'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown gender value "m", gender value should be [female, male]]
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:121)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:129)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:116)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1099)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:670)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2508)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2497)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
```

Comment: Use java.lang.Throwable#getCause

Comment: **What** `BindException`? There isn't any such thing in the code or output you posted.

Comment: @SurenSrapyan Edit rejected. Don't use quote formatting for text that isn't quoted, and do use code formatting for text that is either code or computer output, as the OP already did. Correctly.

Comment: i don't understand your meaning a little, and what's the "OP"?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to read about [BeanPropertyBindingResult](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/BeanPropertyBindingResult.html), as per documentation below:

> Default implementation of the Errors and BindingResult interfaces, for
> the registration and evaluation of binding errors on JavaBean objects.
>
> Performs standard JavaBean property access, also supporting nested
> properties. Normally, application code will work with the Errors
> interface or the BindingResult interface. A DataBinder returns its
> BindingResult via DataBinder.getBindingResult().

According to above description, `Spring` validation framework **throw this error whenever the validation fails** and similar thing is happening in your code as well as for `Gender` class defined under package `org.tings.learning.spring.mvc.model` you are sending `m` and `Spring` is not able to find the specific value in `Gender` enum and asking for you to give either male or female as an input:

as per the error logs:

> Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type
> [@javax.validation.constraints.NotNull
> org.tings.learning.spring.mvc.model.Gender] for value 'm'; nested
> exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown gender value
> "m", gender value should be [female, male]]

Answer (score 0):

Recurse through getCause until you hit null or use https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/exception/ExceptionUtils.html#getRootCause(java.lang.Throwable)

Comment: there's no real root exception, but the BindException's default message contains the nested exception

Comment: Have you tried http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/BindException.html#getFieldErrors-- ?